# Adding custom 503 error page to NGINX container

Tags: nginx, error-handling, server

In a kubernetes cluster we run an NGINX container that serves an error page when the main application is not responding (or takes too long), this is always an 503 error. To do this, we add the custom page as `/usr/share/nginx/html/custom_error.html` and we load in the configuration to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. The configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen  [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    recursive_error_pages on;

    location = /custom_error.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index custom_error.html;
        internal;
    }

    error_page 503 /custom_error.html;

    location / {
        error_page 405 =503 /custom_error.html;
        return 503;
    }
}
```

The server gets to handle the request (when necessary) and it also returns a 503 on every request (that is what the `error_page 405` is for, otherwise POST requests would get 405 errors).

But the custom html is not loaded, is there something missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

the placement of `error_page` is wrong. it has to be placed inside of the `location` blocks that you want to apply it.

```
    # ⛔ wrong placement
    # (outside location bracket)
    # error_page 503 /custom_error.html;

    location / {
        error_page 405 =503 /custom_error.html;
        return 503;
        # ✅ correct placement
        error_page 503 /custom_error.html;
    }
```

check out running demo on [github repo](https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/tree/main/75520763-nginx-503-custom-page)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. I thought I tried to move everything, but forgot this one unfortunately...